# bootstrap 4 border overlap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 my project. below is my code

```css
.form-info-tab {
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-collapse: separate;
     border-spacing: 0px;
     padding:5px;
     text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-info-tab">
   <i class="fas fa-hourglass-half"></i>
   <label class="modalLables">One </label>
</span>
    
<span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-info-tab">
   <i class="fas fa-hourglass-half"></i>
   <label class="modalLables">Two</label>
</span>
```

my issue is, right borders overlapping. how i stop it.

below is the my issue. please check image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove right border from every tab **except** last of type. `:last-of-type` selector is applied to the last element of its type among siblings. The `:not` reverses the selector, so `:not(:last-of-type)` will match everything except for the last item.

As an alternative you can go right to left, by removing left border from every item except for the first one as well. Then you would need the `:first-of-type` selector instead.

```css
.form-info-tab {
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-collapse: separate;
     border-spacing: 0px;
     padding:5px;
     text-align:center;
}

.form-info-tab:not(:last-of-type) {
     border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- this div is just a wrapper to add some padding around tabs -->
<!-- it's not necessary, just for demonstration -->
<div class="p-3">
    <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-info-tab">
       <i class="fas fa-hourglass-half"></i>
       <label class="modalLables">One </label>
    </span>
        
    <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-info-tab">
       <i class="fas fa-hourglass-half"></i>
       <label class="modalLables">Two</label>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: where the border-top in your answer ??

Comment: @gihankumara What do you mean border-top? Question is about right/left borders, isn't it? If you mean, that they are not clearly visible in the snippet - it's just because it collapsed with the frame. I've edited your code snippet to make it less confusing, but I'll add a wrapper div with a padding just to be sure.